# Sort List in Descending Order via Array Count

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort a list of data I get from my database in descending order by the amount of upvotes held in each record. This is what I have currently but does not work. ***NOTE: the upvotes field is a string[] array within the model class.***

```
//Method to get all popular posts and display them in a list
    public async void GetPostInfo()
    {
        PostsMod = new ObservableCollection<IPosts>();
        var temp = await _postsProxy.GetAllPosts();

        if (temp != null)
        {
            if (temp.Count > 0)
            {
                var orderedList = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpVoteId.Count()).ToList(); //Orders the records in descending order based on how many upvotes they contain, puts it into a new list

                foreach (var item in orderedList)
                {
                    PostsMod.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
                PostsMod.Add(temp[0]);
        }
    }
```

All posts are put into a var temp and then the temp list is supposed to be ordered in descending order via the amount of upvotes counted.Keep in mind that again the upvote field is a string[] array in the model class.

It comes up with an error message: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'

**EDIT: Sorry it was a mistake on my part, I made the stupid mistake of the fields in the model class not matching. Therefore resulting in my upvotes being null.**

Comment: "...but does not work." That leaves a lot of guessing on our part.

Comment: Sorry I've edited the code now as that temp was a mistake there, it still doesn't work however.

Comment: So you're saying `UpVoteId` is actually an array and not an Id as it's name implies?  Because if it's a `string` then you're ordering on the number of characters in that id.

Comment: That error message makes me think that one of the `UpVoteId`s might be `null`.

Comment: UpVoteId is suppose to be just upvote, I just forgot to change it my bad.

Comment: It might be helpful if you can post a sample data that you get to see why this is not working.

Comment: It is fixed now, It seems it was a stupid mistake on my end, the field names in the model class were wrong, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

`System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'` comes from a null [IEnumerable`<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1) passed to a Linq extension method, the only one from your code being [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1).

Try this:

```cs
var orderedList = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpVoteId?.Count()).ToList();
```

This will fail since `temp.Count` will be 0:

```
else
    PostsMod.Add(temp[0]);
```

That being said and althought not part of the problem, you should not return a null here. You should always get a collection, empty or not or throw an exception instead of swallowing it.

```cs
if (temp != null)
```